# Python: Imported file displaying old information

Tags: python, python-import, python-importlib

Surely this isn't as complicated as I'm making it out to be. I have a file storing user credentials which we'll call `logins.py`. My main script `app.py` writes new account details to `logins.py`'s lists `userkeys` and `passkeys`. To append new information to the credentials file `app.py` has to import `logins.py` before writing the new information. Problem is that when I do this old information is written to the file - items on the list I erased some time ago. Spooky. Here's some of my code:

```
import logins
def createAccount(self, userkey, passkey):
    if userkey in logins.userkeys:
        return False
    else:
        logins.userkeys.append(userkey)
        logins.passkeys.append(passkey)
        with open('logins.py', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(logins.userkeys + logins.passkeys))
```

If I enter a userkey of `aaa` and a passkey of `bbb` I get

```
userkeys = [12345, 'aaa']
passkeys = ['67890', 'bbb']
```

12345 and 67890 are old userkeys and passkeys that I erased many moons ago that keep coming back. `importlib.reload` makes no difference. What am I missing?

Comment: Just a thought, is there a logins.pyc file and b: why are you importing it?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony No .pyc file to be found. I might be doing something wrong but I am importing logins to append new data to already-existing information in an easy way.

Comment: Unless there is code in logins.py, I don't see why you wouldn't just open it as a file and read the contents. In fact you are already opening it and strangely with 'w' so you are overwriting the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the content of the logins.py?

EDIT: I'm not sure how to solve your problem exactly how you want to, but I would have to offer a better solution, and heres why: Youre importing a file, and then also opening that file and writing to it. That's a little dirty. Try instead storing that stuff in a csv file. python makes csv file reading/writing really easy and I think you'll appreciate them down the road.

Comment: As I mentioned in the original post all you will find is `userkeys = [12345, 'aaa']
passkeys = ['67890', 'bbb'] `, which is intentional - just not the data!